# Altitude information for European highways

Tags: dem, slope, road, altitude

I need to calculate the gradient in major European highways. Fot this I need altitude data for each highway, let's say every 100 meters.
Are there such kind of data publicly available? If not, I am also interested in commercial ones.

I have already tried to use DEM GeoTIFF images, but since the DEM depicts the "bare earth", they are not accurate enough for my purpose.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What's wrong with the shuttle SRTM data? Other, than that it is a bit outdated.

Comment: To my understanding the SRTM data show the "bare earth", while the highways may reside in a different "layer". For example, a highway is almost level even if it passes through a hilly territory. Bridges and tunnels are also missing from the DEM. Am I wrong? Does the SRTM has such details?

Comment: GrapHopper API has routes with Elevation (source graph.elevation.provider=srtm) see https://docs.graphhopper.com/#operation/getRoute